# Writing a clock(loop) that is triggered in the mhz consistently and effeciently for an emulator in modern C++

Tags: c++, cross-platform, emulation, c++20

I'm currently developing an emulator for an old CPU (intel 8085). Said CPU clock is 3.2mhz. I'm trying to be as accurate as possible, and as cross-platform as possible

To me, that means I need a clock that gets called with a frequency of 3.2mhz. I don't care about it being too accurate, anything within 10% accuracy is good enough.

The easy way is

```cpp
auto _PrevCycleTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
double _TimeBetweenClockCycles = 1.0 / 3200000;
while (1)
{
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(now - _PrevCycleTime);
    
    if (t.count() >= _TimeBetweenClockCycles)
    {
        _PrevCycleTime = now;
        //Clock trigger
    }
}
```

That produces a clock that's called 2.4 million times a second.
The bigger problem is that I realised is that even running a `while(1) {}` uses 50-60% of my CPU. So that won't do.

My next approach is using a sleep function.

```cpp
long long _TimeBetweenClockCyclesNS = 1000000000 / 3200000
double _TimeBetweenClockCycles = 1.0 / 3200000;
auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

while (_Running)
{
    std::chrono::duration<double> t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(now - _PrevCycleTime);

    if (t.count() >= _TimeBetweenClockCycles)
    {
        _PrevCycleTime = now;
        //Clock trigger
    }
    else
    {            
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(_TimeBetweenClockCyclesNS));
    }
}
```

while that (somewhat) works, it's not consistent at all. I want it to be just "close enough", but the above code gets called:

- 100.000 times / second in Visual Studio debug mode (<3% cpu usage)
- 1.7 million times / second in Visual Studio debug mode using 1 nanosecond sleep time instead but again ~30% cpu usage.
- 100 times / second (yes, only 100, no other change in code) in Visual Studio Release mode (<1% cpu usage)
- Even using `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(1))` the clock is only triggered 1200 times a second.

I'm most likely missing something obvious and I'm over-complicating it but I'm sure there must be a better way, since other emulators of much "heavier" systems seem to use less CPU while requiring much more accuracy.

In my use case, I mostly care about:

- Being cross-platform, but I don't mind writing different code for different OS
- Not using an absurd amount of resources
- I don't care about it not being *very* accurate, as long as it does not have too much of an effect on the timing of the CPU. (For example, if a "wait" routine is supposed to wait for 1 second, I don't really mind if it's 0.8 or 1.2 seconds)

What are my options?

(*Note:* Without any clock limiting logic, my clock can run more than 30 million times a second. Again, using about 50-60% of my CPU. So it *should* be able to run at 3million times at a much lower CPU usage)

(*Note:* The code runs in a separate std::thread if that matters)

Comment: Real emulators do not work this way. If your emulator runs 10x as fast as it's supposed to, then it needs to sleep 90% of the time to slow down, but it doesn't need to sleep every single clock cycle! It can sleep 0.9 milliseconds out of every 1.0 milliseconds for example. More realistically it would probably sleep every video frame and nobody could tell that the CPU ran fast between frames.

Comment: The system you are emulating, does it actually have strict timing requirements, like timing where the video chip is displaying when the CPU edits the video chip registers?

Comment: @user253751 I don't understand your first comment. If it sleeps only once for 90% of the time, then the timing is all messed up.

It doesn't have strict timing requirements, nor am I emulating a video chip. Only the CPU and some peripherals. This is for academic purposes, and the accuracy I care about is being able to run a "wait" subroutine written in the CPU's assembly code, that approximately works. As I said, for example if I want to "sleep" for 1 second, I want to approximately sleep for 1 second.

Comment: @user253751 Reading your first comment again: So basically you're saying I should run the clock as fast as possible for (HZ)/(FPS) clock cycles, and then sleep for the remainder of the frame?

Comment: Clock and timing accurate emulation is a very obscure topic. I myself am not well versed in those regards, but I do know a couple of people who are. To be honest, I don't think you'll find a lot of people here on StackOverflow who actually understand the problem at detail, why you've to care about this in the first place, and how to properly implement it. – May I suggest you take a chance at asking about these things at a forum concerned with cycle accurate emulation, like the one of the Higan emulator? https://helmet.kafuka.org/bboard/forum.php?id=6 Much more likely to get proper help there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to recognize is that nobody can notice if some things happen at the wrong time. You have a CPU talking to some peripherals. Let's say the peripherals are GPIO pins. As long as the CPU turns the GPIO pins on and off at the right time, nobody can actually notice if the CPU is running too quickly in between those times. If it drives a display output, nobody can notice if the display pixels are calculated too quickly, as long as they are displayed at the right frame rate. And so on.

---

One technique used by emulators is to count up the number of clock cycles used by the CPU instructions. If you're using an interpreted design you can write `clockCycles += 5;` in the instruction handler. If you're using a JIT design you can do it at the end of each basic block. If you're not using a JIT design and you don't know what a basic block is, you can ignore the previous sentence.

Then, *when the CPU actually does something that matters*, like changing the GPIO pins, you can sleep to catch up. If 3,200,000 clock cycles happened since the last sleep, but it's only been 0.1 seconds of real time, then you can sleep for 0.9 seconds before updating the screen.

The less "sleep points" you have, the less accurate timing you have, and the less time you waste trying to maintain accurate timing. A video game emulator will typically render the whole frame as fast as possible. In fact since the N64/PS1 era, many emulators don't even bother emulating CPU timing at all. The timing on these systems is so complicated that every game already knows it has to wait for the next frame to start, so the emulator just has to start frames at the correct rate.

---

Another idea is to calculate and send timing information to the peripheral without actually timing it. Emulators for earlier systems (e.g. SNES) where games do rely on precise display timing can run the CPU at full speed and then tell the display code "at clock cycle 12345 the CPU wrote 0x6789 to register 12." The display code can then calculate which pixel the display was drawing on that clock cycle, and change how it's drawn. There's still no need to *actually synchronize* the CPU and display timing.

---

If you want precise timing without horribly slowing down the program, you might want to use an FPGA instead of a CPU.

Comment: Thanks! I got a lot of ideas and I think I have a system that works much better now. I just sleep a few times a second to catch up, just so CPU doesn't go too far ahead, but also whenever an "IN" or "OUT" instruction (input through pins, output through pins) is executed, I again sleep to catch up. This seems to have improved both accuracy and CPU usage.